# Get results with whitespace in lucene

Tags: regex, lucene, whitespace

I'm trying to get results with whitespace using Lucene `RegexpQuery`.
Try ever possible search regex text like;

```
[a-z]{4}\s[a-z]{5}
[a-z]{4}( )[a-z]{5}
[a-z]{4}(\s)[a-z]{5}
```

I use (now) basic and use standard methods like;

```
...
IndexWriter writer = createWriter(storePath);
Document docu1 = indexDoc(writer, catchText, Files.getLastModifiedTime(docDir).toMillis(), value.getUniqueId());
documents.add(docu1);
...
writer.addDocuments(documents);
writer.commit();
...
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(writer);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
...
Query q1 = new RegexpQuery(new Term("contents", var.getRuleText()), RegExp.ALL);
...
Document docX = reader.document(idX);
String textX = docX.get("contents");
TokenStream tokenStream = TokenSources.getTokenStream("contents", reader.getTermVectors(idX),textX,new StandardAnalyzer(), -1);
OffsetAttribute offsetAtt = (OffsetAttribute)tokenStream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
```

How can I search with regex containing whitespace using `RegexpQuery`? If `RegexpQuery` can't be used is there any other suggested approach?

Search Text Example:

```
Lorem ipsum test dolor sit amet.
```

Must Result:

```
test dolor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a phrase query with the standard analyzer to select documents containing the word "test" immediately followed by the word "dolor".

The [standard analyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) will tokenize on whitespace, and convert terms to lowercase:

```java
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
```

Then you can build a phrase query as follows:

```java
import org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
```

And:

```java
PhraseQuery.Builder builder = new PhraseQuery.Builder();
builder.add(new Term("phrase", "test"), 1);
builder.add(new Term("phrase", "dolor"), 2);
PhraseQuery phraseQuery = builder.build();
```

More details are provided [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html). In particular, note: *All terms in the phrase must match...*

**Update**

Why does this work, given we tokenized our data on white spaces - thus losing the white spaces? This is because the indexes built by Lucene keep track of the positions of each term from the source documents. Lucene therefore knows which term immediately follows which other term. It can use this data to check whether a multi-term phrase exists in a document, or not.

**Update re. Indexing Requirements**

There are no special requirements when indexing data, if you want to use a phrase query. You can use a standard `TextField`, with no need to store the indexed content:

```java
doc.add(new TextField("content", "Lorem ipsum test dolor sit amet.", Field.Store.NO));
```

This builds a field index which looks something like the following:

```
field content
  term amet
    doc 0
      freq 1
      pos 5
  term dolor
    doc 0
      freq 1
      pos 3
  term ipsum
    doc 0
      freq 1
      pos 1
  term lorem
    doc 0
      freq 1
      pos 0
  term sit
    doc 0
      freq 1
      pos 4
  term test
    doc 0
      freq 1
      pos 2
```

Terms are stored with their frequencies and their positions.

You get this because when you use a `TextField` (which is one of Lucene's pre-built field types) it includes [`IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexOptions.html#DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS) as part of its definition.

You do need to be careful - there are plenty of other pre-defined field types in Lucene, and I expect not all of them capture position data automatically. You can build custom fields which capture exactly what you may need for your situation.

**Update for Regexp**

Given you must use a regexp for this, then one approach is to use a shingles filter. This can be set up as follows in a custom analyzer:

```java
Analyzer shingleAnalyzer = new Analyzer() {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
        Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer();
        TokenStream tokenStream = source;
        tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenStream);
        tokenStream = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(tokenStream);
        tokenStream = new ShingleFilter(tokenStream, 2, 2);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, tokenStream);
    }
};
```

This uses [`ShingleFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html).

Use this analyzer for indexing.

It will create tokens consisting of "shingles" - i.e. multiple consecutive words. In this case, each shingle will be 2 words in length.

So, for the following input document:

```
Lorem ipsum test dolor sit amet
```

The following terms will be indexed:

```
lorem ipsum
ipsum test
test dolor
and so on...
```

As well as the above terms, this will also preserve the single-word terms in your index - so the index data can also be used for other queries.

Or, if you always want exactly two words per shingle, you can use [`FixedShingleFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/FixedShingleFilter.html).  In this case, single-word terms will *not* be included in the index. This keeps the index smaller than `ShingleFilter` but potentially with less flexibility, when it comes to running other types of query.

Now you can use a standard analyzer for querying, together with the regexp query you have been trying to use.

There is no special syntax in Lucene regexp for whitespaces, so the following expression will match a standard whitespace:

```
[a-z]{4} [a-z]{5}
```

To extract the specific matching words from the document, you would need to post-process the document using Java regex handling, or else process the token stream directly.

Comment: Does it always keep track of term position in the doc or is that an additional param that must be set when creating the field for the doc?

Comment: @RonC - thanks for the note - it is an important point. I added some comments to the answer to try to address it.

Comment: @andrewjames thanks for answer. I already use `PhraseQuery` for keyword search. But i need regex search. But your update gave me an idea. Maybe i search like phrasequery (separately) then get results position, if positions are consecutive, i have found the result. its may work but i guess gets slower.

Comment: OK - understood - sorry for the unhelpful direction. In that case, shingles may be relevant. I have updated my answer with some related notes.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what analyzer you used with the `IndexWriter` and whether the field you are searching is a tokenized field.  So for example if the field was a text field that is tokenized, and the analyzer used with the `IndexWriter` removes whitespace as part of it's work to create a token stream, then no you can't use *any* query to match on whitespace since all whitespace was removed by the analyzer when the index was written.

On the other hand if the field you want to search is a non-analyzed string field then, using a `RegexpQuery` to query to that field regarding whitespace should work.

Comment: After not indexing I guess it will not be different from normal regex performance. I wonder how elasticsearch did regex process. they also use lucene.